# onitemclicklistener for popup menu

Tags: android

How can i start a new intent on popupmenu item click. Following is the code that i have tried:

```
public class Profile extends Fragment {
    public Profile() { }

    View vi;
    public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.profile, container, false);
        TextView iv = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.btnprofile_settings);

        iv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                PopupMenu homepopup = new PopupMenu(getActivity(), v);
                MenuInflater inflater = homepopup.getMenuInflater();
                inflater.inflate(R.menu.account_settings, homepopup.getMenu());

                homepopup.show();
            }
        });
        return vi;
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `setOnMenuItemClickListener` on the `PopupMenu` instance like:

```
homepopup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new OnMenuItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(android.view.MenuItem item) {
            return true;
        }
    })
```